# How do I fill the missing values which can't get captured on MouseMove event?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, drawing, mouseevent, mousemove

Is there anyone/ expert who can help me get these missing values which can't get captured on mousemove event?

The video of my project. [[View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVw8lc45wKI)]

My idea is there anyway in which we can get the missing values like,

```
For Each i as even row index and j as odd row index
    If i - j > 2
        Do Until j = i 
            dgv.rows.insert()'code that will increase by +1
```

To determine row index we can say

```
If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
    'even
Else
    'Odd
End  If
```

Again, this isn't any real code. I was just trying to illustrate my idea.

Form code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim drag As Boolean
    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
        If Not drag Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        dgv.Rows.Add((MousePosition.X - Me.Left - 8).ToString, (MousePosition.Y - Me.Top - 34).ToString)
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
        drag = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
        drag = False
        Dim img As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
        Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1
            gfx.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value), Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value), 5, 5)
        Next
        PictureBox1.Image = img
    End Sub
End Class
```

Application screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What missing values? Don't make us go off-site and watch a video when you can simply write a FULL and CLEAR description right here.

Comment: Okay, I am updating with the code. But I thought providing a video is a good way to explain the problem.

Comment: Okay you can check now. I have updated the question.

Comment: You will get the values as fast as you can process them. That means the events will keep being raised as quickly as you can handle them. If you need intermediate values, then you can just interpolate.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I need. I am a bit confuse how to interpolate here. Can you help me with that? Or any link that would give some sample code for it and tutorials or any other staffs that would help me in this.

Comment: if you process and get the values fast more than one per second your middle missing values will generally be a straight line from value n to n+1 as the mouse on short trip will be in straight lines from two points

Comment: @Mederic Can you illustrate a code about it?

Comment: try to understand it first

Comment: `generally be a straight line from value n to n+1 as the mouse on short trip will be in straight lines`, a ***strong generally***, but it may not be...

Comment: @Mederic Yeah I understand you point but not being able to implement in this case. Please little coding might help or any other link for similar case.

Comment: You should draw a line between the point where the mouse is now and the previous location of the mouse. Dont fill an ellipse, slow and not needed...

Comment: @MohammadZulfikar I don't have any links since just thought of it.
Lets say: N the time now and N-1 the the previous spot. Hence we have: **XN, YN** and **XN-1, YN-1** for coordinates then you just need to fill the blank: for example for N: **150.0, 80.0** and for N-1: **155.0, 75.0** you would get something like N-0.5: **152.5, 77.5** This however is only viable if the time between two points is short probably around **<  100 ms (personal though)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay!

First of all thank you everyone for the comments (Suggestions). Finally I found the solution to get rid of this problem. I didn't found this solution nor any similar by searching in the net except Microsoft Support page for drawing curves. I hope this solution will help bunch of future readers to overcome the dashes while drawing on MouseMove Event. So without any further talking let me provide you the solution.

Solution Code:

```
Public Class Form2
Dim drag As Boolean
Dim img As Bitmap = New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
Dim imgPartial As Bitmap = New Bitmap(img)
Dim gfxPartial As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgPartial)

Dim mouseX As Integer
Dim mouseY As Integer
Dim fixCurve() As Point
Dim redPen As New Pen(Color.Red, 3)
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove, Panel1.MouseMove
    If drag Then

        mouseX = (MousePosition.X - Me.Left - 8)
        mouseY = (MousePosition.Y - Me.Top - 34)
        gfxPartial.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, MousePosition.X - Me.Left - 8, (MousePosition.Y - Me.Top - 34), 3, 3)
        PictureBox1.Image = imgPartial
        fixCurve(UBound(fixCurve)) = New Point(mouseX, mouseY)
        ReDim Preserve fixCurve(UBound(fixCurve) + 1)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown, Panel1.MouseDown
    drag = True
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp, Panel1.MouseUp
    drag = False
    'Here's the magic begin!!!
    ReDim Preserve fixCurve(fixCurve.Length - 2)
    gfx.DrawCurve(redPen, fixCurve)
    PictureBox1.Image = img
    gfxPartial.Clear(Color.White)
    gfxPartial.DrawImage(img, New Point(0, 0))
    ReDim fixCurve(0)
End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ReDim fixCurve(0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Advantages:

This solution overcomes the use of DataGridView and instead it uses the function of Arrays to store the mouse positions.